# Integration between My SQL and Jasper Reports

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have MySQL server installed at `C:\[product name]\mysql-5.0.22-win` on my machine . But what should i specify in the JasperAssistant Data Source inside Eclipse for the following fields:-

```
- Name
- Driver
- URL
```

BR

Answer (score 1):

I have never used JasperAssistant... but surely it's looking for this:

```
Name:   Some Connection Name (whatever you like)
Driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
URL:    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lotsodata
```

Your database might not be called "lotsodata". You'll need to fill in the actual name of your database.